# Get value of date from object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-date, typescript-template-literals

I have an object array and need to access the value of each date. I need to go through each date value and check them against the current date.
It's I'mportant that the returned date value is in the format of `DD/MM/YYYY` without showing the time.

P.S apologies, I'm new to Javascript and I'm not quite If I'm even doing this the right way

I appreciate any advise!

```
const menu = [
 {
 id: 1,
 title: "title of item one",
 date: "22/12/2023",
 },
 {
 id: 2,
 title: "title of item two",
 date: "01/02/2024",
 },
 {
 id: 3,
 title: "title of item three",
 date: "18/04/2024",
 },
]

let objectDate = menu.date;

let date = new Date();
let day = date.getDate();
let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
let year = date.getFullYear();

const currentDate = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

for (let i=0; i < menu.length; i++) {

 if (currentDate > objectDate) {
  // objectDate = "Sorry, this offer is expired";
  console.log("Sorry this deal is expired");
 }
 else if (currentDate === objectDate) {
  //objectDate = "This offer expires TODAY!";
  console.log("Hurry! Expires TODAY");
 }
 else {
  //objectDate = "Offer expires on " + objectDate;
  console.log("Expires on " + objectDate);
 }
};
```

Comment: Where are you getting stuck with this?

Comment: You are going to have to compare _full `Date` objects_, because you can't compare strings like that. It's just the _output_ you want to format to your specific string. Internally, everything should just be `Date`, then you can just use `Date > Date` and `Date < Date`.

Answer (score 0):

1. you're have in JSON a date separated by "/", but set it to a variable via "-"
2. you are comparing strings when you should compare numbers. Study, if you don’t know, type conversions, and then compare: first year with year, then month with month, and, if the rest are equal, day with day.

right code:

```
const menu = [
 {
 id: 1,
 title: "title of item one",
 date: "22-12-2023",
 },
 {
 id: 2,
 title: "title of item two",
 date: "01-02-2024",
 },
 {
 id: 3,
 title: "title of item three",
 date: "18-04-2024",
 },
]

let objectDate = menu[0].date;

let currentDate = new Date();
let currentDay = date.getDate();
let currentMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
let currentYear =  date.getFullYear();


for (let i=0; i < menu.length; i++) {

 if (currentYear >  parseInt(objectDate.slice(0,2)) or currentMonth > parseInt(objectDate.slice(4,6)) or currentDay > parseInt(objectDate.slice(8,10))) {
  // objectDate = "Sorry, this offer is expired";
  console.log("Sorry this deal is expired");
 }
 else if (currentDate === objectDate) {
  //objectDate = "This offer expires TODAY!";
  console.log("Hurry! Expires TODAY");
 }
 else {
  //objectDate = "Offer expires on " + objectDate;
  console.log("Expires on " + objectDate);
 }
};
```

Comment: Maybe help a guy out an show them how to convert, then compare. That would be an answer. This is, at most, a comment.

Comment: @Prog thanks! I've just been studying javascript for 2 weeks now and thought to give it a try and create a little project by myself! Clearly I'm not ready for that yet lol.  I do have one question, I'm not quite sure if I understand how "or" is being used in the if statement. Again sorry if the question is too obvious

Comment: @user23321762, for currentData to be greater than objectData, OR year must be greater than OR month OR day. If all of this is no more, the program moves on.

Comment: @user23321762, sorry for my immodesty, but if I helped you in any way, you can thank me by clicking on the up arrow and the checkmark next to my answer)

Comment: @prog Ah thanks I get it now. One question though, using your solution, it seems like only the first date is being repeated three times rather than it checking for all three dates. Could you please explain how I can check for the date within each object?

Comment: @user23321762, you need to create a loop `for(let i=0; i<menu.length; i++)`, wrap the conditions in one loop and inside the loop write not `objectDate`, but `objectDate[i]`, since you have `json` in the list and you can access them by indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the object date in for loop. so that you can access the current iteration date **menu[i].date**. Also create the current date variable with DD/MM/YYYY format instead of DD-MM-YYYY.

Try this two changes.

Comment: Maybe write how to do it instead of just suggesting it and saying "try it yourself". That would be an answer. this is, at most, a comment (which I know you can't do yet, but then try to make a nice, good answer that helps a bit more with how to accomplish the things you describe here, as the OP clearly isn't at that point as a programmer yet)

Comment: I agree with your feedback. Thanks :).

Comment: Have you seen this line of question.. he want to check each date in the object.. your code will only check the first date from obj... isn't it?

Comment: My code? Are you replying to me?

Answer (score 0):

There are way too many problems in your code, I don't even know where to start !
Here is a possible solution, you should study it.

PS: Stackoverflow is not a place to receive programming lessons.

```js
const
  menu = 
    [ { id: 1, title: 'title of item one',   date: '22/12/2023' } 
    , { id: 2, title: 'title of item two',   date: '30/01/2024' } 
    , { id: 3, title: 'title of item three', date: '18/04/2025' } 
    ] 
, now  = new Date()  // = today Date + Hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds
, DD   = String( now.getDate()    ).padStart(2, '0') // Numeric values must be replaced by a string 
, MM   = String( now.getMonth() +1).padStart(2, '0') // with a leading zero for 2 full digits.
, YYYY = now.getFullYear()
, currentDate = YYYY + MM + DD // in algebraic order, years come first
  ;
for (let row of menu) 
  {
  let 
    [dd,mm,yyyy] = row.date.split('/') // values are separated by slashes, not hyphens
  , ymd          = yyyy + mm + dd      // transpose d/m/y to ymd
    ;
  switch ( currentDate.localeCompare(ymd) ) // for String type use localeCompare() method
    {
    case 0:
      console.log("Hurry! Expires TODAY -->", row.date );
      break;
    case 1:
      console.log("Sorry this deal is expired -->", row.date );
      break;
    default: // or -1
      console.log("Expires on " + row.date );
    }
  }
```